# Show null values in SQL query with multiple joins

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that does not return any rows when there are no material codes present inside the `MaterialCodes` table that have the `vendorId` that is passed.  How can I get the MaterialCode column to show null when nothing matches

Here's my query

```
SELECT 
    Materials.Id, Materials.Type, Materials.Name, Materials.Thickness, 
    Materials.Width, Materials.Length, Materials.Grain, MaterialCodes.Code
FROM 
    dbo.HFCMaterialsDVI AS DVIMaterials
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.HFCMaterials AS Materials ON DVIMaterials.Id = Materials.ParentId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.HFCMaterialsCode as MaterialCodes ON Materials.Id = MaterialCodes.MaterialId
WHERE 
    DVIMaterials.Name = 'Fashionista' 
    AND MaterialCodes.VendorId = 2
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use a left join

Comment: I have tried that

Comment: Then you should have shown this query. You probably left `WHERE VendorId = 2`, which then turned your outer join into an inner join, because in an outer joined row the vendor ID is null. Conditions on outer joins belong in the `ON` clause, as shown in my answer.

Comment: And please always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS. Are you using Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer join, so as to keep materials that have no matchong materials code for the desired vendor. I would also move the HFCMaterialsDVI table to an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause, because you merely want to ensure that the material has such a match.

The query:

```
SELECT m.id, m.type, m.name, m.thickness, m.width, m.length, m.grain, mc.code
FROM dbo.hfcmaterials AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hfcmaterialscode AS mc ON mc.materialid = m.Id
                                          AND mc.vendorid = 2
WHERE m.parentid IN (SELECT id FROM dbo.hfcmaterialsdvi WHERE name = 'Fashionista')
```

(The `OUTER` keyword is optional, so if you want to you can shorten `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.)